# $form_state->setError on autocomplete field

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with custom validation and an autocomplete field. I have no problem to set errors for text fields, for example for a List (text) field I can say

```
  $fss = $form_state->getValue('field_substructure') ;
  if (! $fss || $fss[0]['value'] == '_none')
      $form_state->setError($form['field_substructure']['widget'], 'Insert a value for the substructure') ;
```

For my autocomplete field, using `ksm($form)` I see that the widget appears to be at `$form['field_structure']['widget'][0]['target_id']`, so I write

```
  if (! $form_state->getValue('field_structure'))
      $form_state->setError($form['field_structure']['widget'][0]['target_id'], 'Insert a value for the structure') ;
```

If I left the field empty, the error appears, but the field is not marked with the red border. Just to be on the safe side, as first argumente to setError() I also tried to use `$form['field_structure']['widget'][0]`, `$form['field_structure']['widget']` and `$form['field_structure']`. Maybe the autocomplete field misses a css?

Comment: You say when you `ksm` the form the autocomplete is called, `$form['field_autocomplete']`, but you set the error on `$form['field_structure']`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the text, I had to make some minor change to my code for posting it and I did a mistake. I will correct it in the text. Thank you for taking the time to read carefully my question!

Comment: Ok, have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Every time I added a validation to a field--so yes, amny times during my tests :)